# C# - LINQ query returns null to table and throws exception

Tags: c#, linq, exception

I have a piece of code:

```
var tblGroupedMultiPassive = dtCSV.AsEnumerable()
                                  .Where(r => r.Field<String>("course_type_id") == "3")
                                  .GroupBy(r => new
                                  {
                                       product_id = r.Field<String>("product_id"),
                                       owner_org_id = r.Field<String>("owner_org_id"),
                                  });

if (tblGroupedMultiPassive.Count() > 0)
    dtCSVMultiSCOPassive = tblGroupedMultiPassive.Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1)
                                                 .SelectMany(grp => grp)
                                                 .CopyToDataTable();
```

Basically on the final statement where assigning to dtCSVMultiSCOPassive, it throws an exception for there being no rows.  I know there are rows before this query so it's got to be the LINQ query itself eliminating all of the rows.  This is fine, but I need to be able to deal with this situation without it becoming an exception.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is that the entire query?  Where's your grouping statement?  Are you certain that there are cases where your grouping included more than one row?

Comment: that is the part throwing the exception.  I will edit the post and include the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to break this into two statements:

```
DataTable dtCSVMultiSCOPassive = new DataTable();

var query = tblGroupedMultiPassive.Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1).SelectMany(grp => grp);

if(query.Any())
{
    dtCSVMultiSCOPassive = query.CopyToDataTable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would appear that `grp.Count()` is always 1, which would indicate that you have unique combinations of `product_id` and `owner_org_id` in your first query.

BTW, I believe that `.SelectMany(grp => grp)` is completely redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this statement doesn't return null:

```
dtCSVMultiSCOPassive = tblGroupedMultiPassive.Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1);
```

?

So because of the first conditional `tblGroupedMultiPassive.Count() > 0` seems to be true I would try:

```
if (tblGroupedMultiPassive.Count() > 0)
{
    dtCSVMultiSCOPassive = tblGroupedMultiPassive.Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1);

    if(dtCSVMultiSCOPassive != null)
       dtCSVMultiSCOPassive = dtCSVMultiSCOPassive.CopyToDataTable();
}
```

Infact the problem could be that almost every `grp` contains only one element so the query returns null becuase of the second conditional `grp.Count() > 1` in your query.